# Neural network only works on simple linearly separable problems

Tags: java, neural-network

I recently implemented a simple neural network in Java. 
I'm stuck at implementing backpropagation. 
When solving a simple problem like OR, AND, NOT, ect., my network works fine (I'm doing approximately 1000 backprop cycles) even when I use more than two layers.
However, once I try doing more complex functions like XOR, XNOR, etc. (I use a 2-2-1 network), my network fails and outputs strange values.

I'm following [this](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html) article, which explains the math very well, but I think my code is failing when I backpropagate the error.

Here is my code:

```
public class NeuralNetwork {

    private int layers;
    private Matrix[] weights;
    private Vector[] biases;

    private Function<Double, Double> afunc = d -> 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -d));
    private Function<Double, Double> afuncder = d -> { double sig = 1 / (1 + Math.pow(Math.E, -d)); return sig * (1 - sig); };

    private BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> cfunc = (x, y) -> { double diff = y - x; return 0.5 * diff * diff; };
    private BiFunction<Double, Double, Double> cfuncder = (x, y) -> x - y;

    public NeuralNetwork() { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Neural network must have at least two layers"); }
    public NeuralNetwork(int n) { throw new IllegalArgumentException("Neural network must have at least two layers"); }

    public NeuralNetwork(int... layers) {
        this.layers = layers.length - 1;

        weights = new Matrix[this.layers];
        biases = new Vector[this.layers];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.layers; ++i) {
            weights[i] = new Matrix(layers[i + 1], layers[i]);
            biases[i] = new Vector(layers[i + 1]);
        }
    }

    public Vector forward(Vector input) {
        Vector activation = input;

        for (int i = 0; i < layers; ++i) {
            activation = activation.mul(weights[i]);
            activation = activation.add(biases[i]);
            activation = activation.forEach(afunc);
        }

        return activation;
    }

    public double cost(Vector input, Vector desOutput) {
        Vector res = forward(input);

        double cost = 0.0d;

        for (int i = 0; i < res.size(); ++i)
            cost += cfunc.apply(res.get(i), desOutput.get(i));

        return cost;
    }

    public void backward(Vector[] input, Vector[] desOutput, int batchSize, double learningRate) {
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; ++i) {
            Vector[] z = new Vector[layers];
            Vector[] a = new Vector[layers];

            Vector activation = input[i];

            for (int j = 0; j < layers; ++j) {
                activation = activation.mul(weights[j]).add(biases[j]);
                z[j] = activation;

                activation = activation.forEach(afunc);
                a[j] = activation;
            }

            Vector out = a[layers - 1];

            Vector costGrad = new Vector(out.size());

            for (int j = 0; j < out.size(); ++j)
                costGrad.set(j, cfuncder.apply(out.get(j), desOutput[i].get(j)));

            Vector[] err = new Vector[layers];

            err[layers - 1] = costGrad.hadamard(z[layers - 1].forEach(afuncder));

            for (int j = layers - 2; j >= 0; --j)
                err[j] = weights[j + 1].transpose().mul(err[j + 1]).hadamard(z[j].forEach(afuncder));

            for (int k = 0; k < weights[0].rows(); ++k) {
                for (int l = 0; l < weights[0].columns(); ++l)
                    weights[0].set(k, l, weights[0].get(k, l) - err[0].get(k) * input[i].get(l) * learningRate);

                biases[0].set(k, biases[0].get(k) - err[0].get(k) * learningRate);
            }

            for (int j = 1; j < layers; ++j) {
                for (int k = 0; k < weights[j].rows(); ++k) {
                    for (int l = 0; l < weights[j].columns(); ++l)
                        weights[j].set(k, l, weights[j].get(k, l) - err[j].get(k) * a[j - 1].get(l) * learningRate);

                    biases[j].set(k, biases[j].get(k) - err[j].get(k) * learningRate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I implemented the Matrix and Vector classes myself and have tested them to make sure they work.
When doing simple neural networks like this:

```
NeuralNetwork nn = new NeuralNetwork(2, 1);

Vector[] input = {
    new Vector(0, 0),
    new Vector(1, 0),
    new Vector(0, 1),
    new Vector(1, 1)
};

Vector[] output = {
    new Vector(0),
    new Vector(0),
    new Vector(0),
    new Vector(1)
};

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    nn.backward(input, output, 4, 1.0);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    System.out.println(input[i] + " Output: " + nn.forward(input[i]));
```

The output looks something like this:

```
(0, 0) Output: (0.002)
(1, 0) Output: (0.02)
(0, 1) Output: (0.02)
(1, 1) Output: (0.93)
```

which is pretty good. 
If I setup a more complex network:

```
NeuralNetwork nn = new NeuralNetwork(2, 2, 1);

Vector[] input = {
    new Vector(0, 0),
    new Vector(1, 0),
    new Vector(0, 1),
    new Vector(1, 1)
};

Vector[] output = {
    new Vector(0),
    new Vector(1),
    new Vector(1),
    new Vector(0)
};

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    nn.backward(input, output, 4, 1.0);

for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    System.out.println(input[i] + " Output: " + nn.forward(input[i]));
```

My output looks pretty bad:

```
(0, 0) Output: (0.3)
(1, 0) Output: (0.3)
(0, 1) Output: (0.3)
(1, 1) Output: (0.02)
```

If more information is needed, I'd be glad to provide it and if anyone can spot my mistake, I'd be very grateful, thanks!

/* EDIT */

I've since tried randomizing all of my weights and biases before I do backpropagation and now I get the right outcome half of the time. The other half looks something like this:

```
(0, 0) Output: (0.04) // correct
(1, 0) Output: (0.48) // incorrect
(0, 1) Output: (0.97) // correct
(1, 1) Output: (0.48) // incorrect
```